# Trying to check if value already in MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am writing a script that will run every 20 minutes that looks for files to download but I want to check if I have already dowloaded the file:
First my code executes this command:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT `file_id` FROM `reports`")
file_ids = list(cursor.fetchall())
```

file_ids is a longer version of this:

```
[('735724',), ('734791',), ('735934',), ('735486',)]
```

I wrote this function to check if I had already downloaded the file:

```
def new_file(file):
    file = "('%s',)" % (file)
    if (file in file_ids):
        print "true"
    else:
        print "false"
```

When I try to to test the function:

```
file = "735724"
new_file(file)
```

It prints false consistently.

What am I doing wrong?

I know that I could run a MySQL statement for each fileid to see if I have the file already but since there are thousands of files to check I assumed doing this would be faster.  If I am wrong on that please feel free to correct me.

Comment: change `file = "('%s',)" % (file)` to `file = (file,)` and your code will work as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results from the database is not a string, it's a list of tuples. What you probably want to do is build a list with just the ids, then check if that numeric value is in the list. For example:

```
file_ids = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
is_in_list = test_id in file_ids
if is_in_list:
    print "true"
```

Comment: Possible performance improvement: `file_ids = set(row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall())`.  This speeds the membership test.

Comment: jimstandard could also rewrite the query so it would just pull what he needs.  `WHERE FILE_ID NOT IN ('735724','735728')` etc.  Or write retrieved `file_ids` in a dedicated table.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to convert everything to string.
try:

```
def new_file(file):
  return (file, ) not in file_ids
```